# How to have diagonal labels in R Corrgram?

Tags: r, correlation, diagonal

Corrgram docs have been misleading, since 2012, as discussed in the email thread [how to change variable names in corrgram diagonal](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-change-variable-names-in-corrgram-diagonal-td4640156.html) about putting labels on the diagonal. 
Many users think wrongly that `diag.panel=...` is  the solution but it is not as seen in the following, but I cannot use `labels` because it is still not yet documented

> yes, the argument "labels" it's working fine!
>
> It would be great if the docs will be be updated also with this already  implemented feature

Code

```
library("corrgram")

ages <- seq(1,18)

corrgram(baseball,
  diag.labels=ages)
```

Output

> There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Fig. 1 Current output without wanted labels on diagonal

[image]

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution

```
corrgram(baseball,
  labels=ages)
```

Output

[image]